# Pycharm/Windows 10 keyboard shortcut clash

Tags: python, windows-10, pycharm

So I am using Pycharm IDE on Windows 10, but in Windows' most recent update they have added a new keyboard shortcut (Alt+Shift+F10) for changing the screen display to negative. The problem is this shortcut is the same as the "Run" shortcut in Pycharm which I use very frequently. As far as I'm aware there is no way to change the keyboard shortcuts in Windows 10, but perhaps there is a way to change shortcuts in Pycharm? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In File -> Settings -> Keymap you can modify the shortcuts the way you want.